# Fit bounds in google map on resize

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to bind the map.fitBounds(bounds) method to a window resize event, unfortunately  without success. Maybe you have an idea?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="http://www.mysite.url/label.js"></script>
<script>

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    panControl: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    center: { lat: 0.0, lng: 40.0},
    zoom: 2
  };

  var destinations = [
    {lat:13.7246005, lng:100.6331108, myTitle:'Bangkok'},
    {lat:8.722049, lng:98.23421, myTitle:'Khao Lak'},
    {lat:1.3146631, lng:103.8454093, myTitle:'Singapore'},
    {lat:-36.8630231, lng:174.8654693, myTitle:'Auckland'},
    {lat:34.0204989, lng:-118.4117325, myTitle:'Los Angeles'},
    {lat:25.782324, lng:-80.2310801, myTitle:'Miami'}
  ];  

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var image = {
     url: 'plane-icon-medium.png',
     size: new google.maps.Size(24, 24),
     origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 12)
   };

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: destinations,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);

  for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
    var myTitle = destinations[i].myTitle;
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(destinations[i].lat, destinations[i].lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: 'test',
        text: myTitle,
    });
    var label = new Label({
       map: map
    });
    label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');
    label.bindTo('text', marker, 'text');
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
     var center = map.getCenter();
     var bounds = map.getBounds();
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
     map.setCenter(center); 
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

</script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Unfortunately, this somehow doesn't work. When I resize the window, the map neither does recenter, nor does it 'rezoom' to fit all markers (i.e. bounds) into the new window.

thanks & best regards,
Klayman

Comment: Scope of `map` variable... define `var map` out of function, make it global. In the function just use `map = new google.maps.Map(...)`.

Comment: Specifically, declare `var map` right up next to where you declare `var bounds`

Comment: What Adam and skobaljic said.  [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edzs1zLh/)

Comment: You can also do the reverse.  Put addDomListener(window, "resize" inside initialize.  Then you can leave all the variables local.  In that case, any function that needs 'map' should be defined within initialize.  http://jsfiddle.net/w1dv62zb/2/

Comment: ok, that did the job. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

ok, the solution is as follows:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="http://www.mysite.url/label.js"></script>
<script>

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);
//globally declare map variable here
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    panControl: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    center: { lat: 0.0, lng: 40.0},
    zoom: 2
  };

  var destinations = [
    {lat:13.7246005, lng:100.6331108, myTitle:'Bangkok'},
    {lat:8.722049, lng:98.23421, myTitle:'Khao Lak'},
    {lat:1.3146631, lng:103.8454093, myTitle:'Singapore'},
    {lat:-36.8630231, lng:174.8654693, myTitle:'Auckland'},
    {lat:34.0204989, lng:-118.4117325, myTitle:'Los Angeles'},
    {lat:25.782324, lng:-80.2310801, myTitle:'Miami'}
  ];  
  //remove declaration of map as already declared globally
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  [...]
```